# Possible to use git submodules for bloom?

Tags: ros, git, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use git submodules in repositories for releasing packages via bloom?

I used it in a package and it succeeded for the devel-build (even on Jenkins), but now the build seems to fail for the binarydeb-jobs because it can't find files from the submodule.

Thanks and best regards,
Sebastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167996/possible-to-use-git-submodules-for-bloom?/) by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1658 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you've answered the question yourself: it doesn't work.

Using git submodules requires extra submodule init and checkout steps that probably don't happen anywhere along the release pipeline.

Working with git submodules tends to be tricky and error-prone, and most of the developers I've met do their best to stay away from them.

Bloom is generally designed to import your codebase from your upstream repository, massage it to produce a git-buildpakage(GBP) repository for each version of Ubuntu you're releasing into, and make that repository available to the build farm.

If you're trying to use git submodules in the GBP repository, don't.

If your upstream repository uses submodules, you'll either have to extend bloom to support submodules, or release the submodules in your project directly.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2017-06-20**:
I've bumped into the same problem and I think the behavior is still the same as three years ago. @Sebastian Kasperski, have you found another workaround?

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2017-07-10**:
Unfortunately not. I had to add my library-code (the previous sub-module) to the ros-package directly, which is not a nice solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just stumbled upon this answer, it seems this is possible now, following the [discussion on github](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/pull/461).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jari](https://answers.ros.org/users/14761/jari/) on 2019-10-15**:
Thank you for the link. I was about to lose all hope